Modeling demographic patterns in voting using Bayes's rule
If a town is 60% orange and 40% not orange and just voted 50% for Party A and 50% for Party B, and we have a prior $\theta$ (maybe from a recent regional election) that gives us $P(A|O,\theta)$ , $P(A|N,\theta)$, $P(O|\theta)$, and $P(N|\theta)$, is it possible to calculate $P(A|O)$ for the town? (Here, $O$ and $N$ are the random variables describing what fraction of the total population are orange and not orange, respectively.) I tried
$$\begin{align*}
P(\theta|A) &\propto P(A|\theta)P(\theta)\\
&= (P(A|O,\theta)P(O|\theta) + P(A|N, \theta)P(N|\theta))P(\theta),\\
\end{align*}$$
but I don't know where to go from here. It seems wrong that $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ don't show up anywhere. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
